# Files Upload on AWS S3 Bucket [android studio]

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files from android studio to AWS S3 Bucket. I have created a new AWS account. This seems to be validation/Authorization Code issue. Can someone please help in figuring out the root cause for this and how can this be solved ?

Please Let me know if any more detail is required.

Thanks,

Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"

            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Warning in Debug Log:

```
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences
I/AmazonHttpClient﹕ Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:674)
            at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:113)
            at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:147)
            at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:94)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:175)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:616)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:487)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:109)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:62)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:353)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4234)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1644)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:134)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:126)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.upload(UploadMonitor.java:182)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:140)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:54)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Code:

```
// Variables Values:
private static final String AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = "078xxxxxxx91";
    private static final String COGNITO_POOL_ID = "eu-west-1:9xxxxx16-4xx2-4xxa-axx1-44cxxxxxxxf5";
    private static final String COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH = "arn:aws:iam::078xxxxxxx91:role/Cognito_ABCUnauth_Role";
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "mybucket";

   private void uploadImagesToServer() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AWSCredentialsProvider credProvider = null;
                    credProvider = getCredProvider(credProvider, getApplicationContext());
                    TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credProvider);
            for(int i=0; i<imagesPath.size(); i++) {
                File file = new File(imagesPath.get(i));
                String fileName = file.getName();
                Upload upload = transferManager.upload(BUCKET_NAME, fileName, file);                        
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
}

public static AWSCredentialsProvider getCredProvider(AWSCredentialsProvider sCredProvider,
                                                     Context appContext) {
    if(sCredProvider == null) {
        sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                appContext,
                AWS_ACCOUNT_ID, COGNITO_POOL_ID, COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH,
                null, Regions.EU_WEST_1);
        sCredProvider.refresh();
    }
    return sCredProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log shows `Request ARN is invalid`. It's because `COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH` is an empty string. Please get the role arn from IAM, or copy the sample code from console.

Then you see `Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` exception. This happens when the credentials provider makes a request to STS to assume the role you specified for session credentials, but your role isn't set to trust Cognito.

Judging by its name, the role was created by you rather than one that is generated by Cognito in the console. I believe you forget to the trust relationship. Go to IAM console, edit the role, scroll all the way down, and click edit Trust Relationships. Make sure you have something like the following (replace pool id with your Cognito identity pool id).

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:<pool_id>"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I tried adding a value for COGNIT O_ROLE_UNAUTH string, the warning log has now changed to Authorization issue.  I am not sure if I need to enter the "IAM user ARN" value or the "Role ARN" value. I have tried both. but not sure if i am entering the correct values. Can you please help here ? Thanks.

Comment: Is this Authentication Error because of the Bucket Policy ?

Comment: Have you enabled unauth access for your identity pool? It's disabled by default when you create an identity pool. Please check your identity pool setting in the AWS console.

Comment: Thanks Yangfan, 'Enable Access to Unauthenticated Identities' box is already checked in (Available in Edit Identity Pool -> Unauthenticated Indentities settings) and the issue is still there.

Comment: Have you checked the trusted relationship of the role? See my reply.

Comment: Trusted Relationship of the role(both Cognito_ABCAuthRole & Cognito_ABCUnAuthRole) is exactly the same as you have specified.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to tell what goes wrong. I hate to make this suggestion, but it may worth a try: recreate a new identity pool, let the console generate IAM roles for you, then modify the roles to allow S3 access.

Comment: Tried few more things. But getting this(Modified Log in original query) as the error in the Debug log now. Any Suggestions to resolve this please ?

Comment: The log shows the connection times out on SSL handshake with AWS. It looks like it successful gets credentials from Cognito, but having trouble connecting to S3. Does it fail all the time? Are you behind firewall or proxy? What model and API level is your device?

Comment: It seems to be working fine now. Thanks for your help & support.